# How do I access the URL that Ember Data will PUT to?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm adapting an old JS (no framework) + Rails app as an Ember learning exercise. The idea of the application is that I'm producing a pdf from some data input. In the initial version, there was no user persistence - you could modify the data provided to you in the tables, and then download the PDF of it.

As part of this, I decided to run with a decidedly non-standard ember framework - I'm essentially using Ember Data to load the initial value of the tables. Ember has been a really natural fit for the models I have on the Rails side, and it's made a lot of the more complicated calculations a lot easier. The issue I have is that my initial idea was that when I came to download the PDF, I'd respond to the "save" action on Ember Data with binary data (with an application/pdf header), which I could then use something like FileSaver.js to serve up to the client. Then, I found that EmberData needs JSON return value.

So I base64 encoded my PDF response and fired it back..but it didn't fit the model schema. I thought I'd then do a manual AJAX save -

```
CalculateYourTV.RostersShowController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions:{
    download: function(){
      var roster = this.get("model");
      var team = roster.get('team');
      return this.ajax('*URL GOES HERE*', record.toJSON(), "PUT").then(function(data) {
        console.log('called')
        console.log(data)
      });
    },
  }
})
```

And this is where I'm currently stuck. Is there any way to access the URL that EmberData is posting to? I could hard-code a route in the Rails side of things, but I don't like hardcoding routes in here, and I'd like to keep it as reusable as possible (I'm planning to eventually allow data persistance).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I am having a similar issue.

Comment: @jax not well sorry - in my case, the route was static (a generic download action), so I changed it to js.erb and hardcoded it. If you are in Rails - https://github.com/railsware/js-routes looks interesting to allow you to access rails routes from the js without using erb.

Answer (score 0):

Just open chrome dev tools (or firebug) and monitor what's going on in the network tab. You should see any ajax request your application sends out, including the EmberData's save request.

Comment: Thanks! :) I already know where the URL is going (it's going to my app after all), but in this context, I have about 50 different rosters, and I didn't want to hard code in the path for each one - so I wanted to read it out of the adapter for the specific roster.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the URL that a specific model will hit by creating custom Ember Data adapters per model.

For example, say you have a `person` model that needs to not hit the default `/persons` URL.

```
App.PersonAdapter = App.ApplicationAdapter.extend({
  pathForType: 'special/custom/endpoint/for/folks'
});
```

That said, Ember Data may not be the best tool here for your PDF "model". You can always use Ember Data for the majority of your models, but use a quick `$.ajax` for other stuff that doesn't fit your definition of a true model.

Comment: Hmm. I looked at $.ajax - the problem I've got is that I need to know how to 'simulate' the data generated from a save. I liked the way ember data serializes all the data. I tried model.toJSON(), but that didn't embed the child objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the adapter to build a URL for you -

```
adapter = @store.adapterFor('application')
url = adapter.buildURL(type, id)
```

where `type` is the name of the model, and `id` is its id.

If want to look up the adapter directly in the container it is

```
@container.lookup('adapter:application')
```